# Object wired instead of solid

Tags: edit-mode, wireframe

In blender 2.8 my object that i try to render looks both in edit and object mode wired, and i can't use smoothen to aussure a plain looking surface.

All the other objects around it are behaving normal and were able to use the smoothen tool.

Does anyone know how i can undo the mistake i probably made and to make the smoothen option usable on the object again?

[image]

Comment: First shot: check the 'Viewport Display' panel in the object's properties.. is 'Display As' set to 'Wire Frame'?

Comment: No, i tried to change the value to rendered or solid but the object remains in this state. It doesn't change but the objects around it do.

They get solid rendered and wireframed when i change the display style

Comment: Just checking.. that is the object's _own_  display properties....